# Use Yahoo Pipes to convert RSS html tags to standard tag items

Tags: regex, rss, yahoo-pipes, delicious-api

I want to move from using bookmarking service Delicious to Diigo, but the way diigo organise tags in their RSS is preventing the move.

I want to use a Yahoo Pipe to turn Diigo rss tags into the same format as Delicious rss tags

Diigo tags are stored as a html list at the bottom of the 'Description' item, like this:

```
Some test describing the link.

<p class="diigo-tags"><strong>Tags:</strong>

    <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href='https://www.diigo.com/user/username/firsttag'>firsttag</a>

    <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href='https://www.diigo.com/user/username/2ndtag'>2ndtag</a>

    <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href='https://www.diigo.com/user/username/anothertag'>anothertag</a>

etc... </p>
```

I need to extract each of these and store them in their own item. Delicious stores each tag in a nested field category by number, like this:

```
category
  0
   domain http://delicious.com/username/
   content firsttag
  1
   domain http://delicious.com/username/
   content 2ndtag
```

So, the Yahoo Pipe needs to strip the html list and separate each tag into single category fields.

Not sure where to start, except maybe this regular expression in regex to strip the html:

```
(?si)<a[^<>]*?[^<>]*>(.*?)</a>
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Please add the link to the pipe in your post

Comment: I made a pipe here, but it doesn't contain much. Good way to compare Diigo and Delicious outputs though:  https://pipes.yahoo.com/machinemachine/8fcfdf5dc9401fb5c6559e4f5d191dfe

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the tags from the diigo stream by performing the following replacements using the **Regex** operator:

- replace `<a[^<>]*?[^<>]*>(.*?)</a>` with `$1`, using options g and s (the tag itself within the `<a>...</a>`)
- replace `<.+>` with nothing, using options g and m (delete all HTML tags)
- replace `[\s]+` with a single space, using options g and s

As a result, the description field now contains the list of tags separated by spaces. I'm not sure what you need next, if you tell me I can try to help.

Here's the pipe:

https://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=1656d9fcab9d9ed6016bdae7486ee71f

**UPDATE**

I see, the tricky part is adding multiple category nodes to an RSS feed. Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible. I updated the pipe, so that now you have `item.category.1`, `.2`, `.3`, and so on, but when you look at the RSS output of the pipe, it doesn't show any categories. (I think this might be related to the fact that the **Create RSS** operator doesn't have a category field either.)

In the JSON output there are multiple categories correctly.

I also tested that if there is only one category field, it would show up correctly in the RSS output. If there are more than one then no.

And I'm afraid this is as far as I can get you.

Comment: This works great, but then next task is to take each of those individual words in 'description' and add them to their own value under category/1, category/2, category/3 etc.  Like this: http://i.imgur.com/ERbRxaK.jpg

Possible? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible :( See my updated answer.

Comment: Dang. Thanks. Do you think there is any other way around this? Is there a way to just split up that list of tags into separate items? As long as they are separate I can do something with them.

Comment: That I can do. See the updated pipe and answer. The categories still won't show up correctly in the RSS output, but at least now you have them in separate elements.

Comment: That does work. And thanks again, but they are still not recognised as valid RSS enclosures at the other end. I have been messing around trying to get it to output properly using Xpath, but I am inexperienced. 

In the delicious feed xml each tag is output as: <category term="TAGNAME1"><category term="TAGNAMETWO"><category term="TAGNAMEMORE"> etc.

See like this: view-source:http://feeds.feedburner.com/Delicious/hugeentity/machinemachine?format=xml

Comment: I know, because I've had this kind of issue before. Yahoo Pipes just won't output custom fields when you view as RSS.